# Loop through list of pandas dataframes and write them to different tabs in one Excel file (from Jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, jupyter

I have a dataframe in my Jupyter notebook that I can successfully write to an Excel file with pandas ExcelWriter, but I'd rather split the dataframe into smaller dataframes (based on its index), then loop through them to write each to a different sheet in one Excel file. This seems syntactically correct but my code cell just runs without ever finishing:

```
path = r'/root/notebooks/my_file.xlsx'

writer = ExcelWriter(path)

sheets = df.index.unique().tolist()

for sheet in sheets:
    df.loc[sheet].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet, index=False)

writer.save()
```

I've tried a few different approaches without any luck. Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to determine the issue in your system without the error message (as you have said, you have an infinite loop). You might check the size of your dataset as you are putting only one row for each excel sheet. If you have plenty of rows, then you will have that many sheets.

However, I tried your code with my own dataset and there are some errors that can be fixed anyway.

```
path = 'raw/test_so.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path)
sheets = df.index.unique().tolist()

for sheet in sheets:
    df.loc[[sheet]].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=str(sheet), index=False)
writer.save()
```

See the `df.loc[[sheet]]` for each sheet to still get the dataframe format on excel (with column headers).

If your dataframe index is in integer, make sure that you do `sheet_name=str(sheet)`, as it can't accept integer for the sheet name.

Comment: Oh, that might be it. I didn't realize it was adding one row at a time. The total data set is about one million rows, being split across 11 sheets.